# How do you get html controls to move together when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have an HTML page with labels and controls. What is the best way to keep the labels with the controls when the browser width is resized smaller?

Here is a simple example:

```
<label id="lbTest1">Enter your first name here:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" />
<label id="lbTest2">Enter your last name here:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtLastName" />
<label id="lbTest3">Enter your preference here:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtPreference" />
```

On resizing of the browser width smaller, the text box, txtPreference, wraps to the next line and then followed by "here:" and then followed by "preference" and so on as the width gets resized smaller.

Here is a link to an image of the results of the above HTML on resize smaller:
[screen snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VplA.png)

I don't want to use tables (at least ideally) and the particular page is too simple to utilize full blown responsiveness.

Comment: You could set the width of the components in a relative size. For instance `20%` or `30vw` Of course at some point, it will break nonetheless

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by 'keep the labels with the controls'. Do you want everything to stay on the same line? Do you want it to wrap more cleanly? What are you expecting to happen? A working code sample of your current implementation and a picture or specific description of what you're after would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flex

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  flex-grow:1;
  min-width:100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>

<p>Try to resize the browser window.</p>
<p>A container with "flex-wrap: nowrap;" will never wrap its items.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Flexbox is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```